# Upgraded to Android Studio 1.4 and ALL LOCAL HISTORY GONE

Tags: android-studio

Is this by design? If so, why?

Should I have known this was possible?

Is it just me or anyone who upgrades from AS 1.2?

Is there any way to get the local history back?

Am I missing something? Am I supposed to NOT rely on local history?

If NOT, why is it there and why have I gotten so much help from it?